# How to analyze log file by using python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on one sample log file from one vending machine. (pretty new to the pandas). Every day the machine will generate one .log file.

Q: How to use python and pandas to extract the info from the .log file, and eventually save the info into a data framework for the next step analysis? (provide sample input and output below)

You can find my sample code and sample .log file below:

```
filePath = "~/sample.log" 
with open(filePath) as fp : 
    line = fp.read()
    print(lines)
```

I am not sure how to approach in this case, could someone please share with me some code to process the above log file? thank you

Comment: Please include a sample of your data as text not as an image.

Comment: Have you tried running that code? Why are you importing pandas when you don't use it? Also, the log file **is** structured

Comment: The file seems to contain this sequence of characters:- '[EVENT_NONE (0)]'. Note the spaces. Therefore your description of that data seems to differ from what's actually found. What **exactly** do you want to extract from the log file(s)?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny@JCaesar thank you so much. There is no space between '[EVENT_NONE (0)]'. Extract each info inside each record.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I have updated the problem. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Python!

You did the correct first step that can read the whole file at a time, but what I am going to show is to use `fp.readline()` to read one line at a time. From [S7.2.1 of doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html),

> if `f.readline()` returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached

We will implement check for end-of-file.

```
with open(filePath, 'r', encoding='utf16') as fp : 
    
    ln = fp.readline() # first line skipped
    ln = fp.readline() # second line skipped

    data = [] # make a list to collect data

    while True:

        ln = fp.readline()

        if ln == '':
            break #end-of-file check

        ln = ln.replace('Battery test speed (mph)', 'BatteryTestSpeed(mph)')

        entities = ln.rstrip('\n').split(' ') # the line is split with space character, so each line will end up with 12 entities

        entities = [entity.split('=')[-1] for entity in entities] # further split each entity with `=` and only preserve the last string. Check for yourself how split works on a string with or without `=`.

        data.append(entities) # collected by the list

    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=...) # put a list of length 12 to specify the column header. Remove `columns=
```

If you had pasted your data in text, I could have tested my code, but now you will need to help in that.

Comment: From the OP's original question... The first two lines are skipped/ignored. There are no blank lines

Comment: Your EOF check makes no sense. At EOF, readline() will return an empty string which you will then try to process in terms of the entities

Comment: @ JCaesar, what I mean is : the final output should ignore the first two lines.

Comment: @JCaesar I just realized the above code will add an extra column in the final output, is there any way to avoid such a case? thank you

Comment: Yes - You can avoid that by not using this so-called 'Answer'

Comment: I think @JCaesar's answer is better than my input, but @Lawrence, from your description, I don't know what you referred as "extra column" is merely extra or it is wrong. If it is just extra, you can drop any unneeded column with `data_df.drop('column-name', axis=1)`.

Comment: @RaymondKwok I have updated my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You said: there will be some spaces in the left side of the "=". Do you think the "extra" column is due to that?

Comment: Anyway, I have added a quick fix `ln = ln.replace('Battery test speed (mph)', 'BatteryTestSpeed(mph)')`

Answer (score 0):

The question itself is full of issues and ambiguities. The line number handling seems very odd. Your question implies that the first line 000 should be ignored. However, this might help you get started

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pandas import DataFrame
import sys

DATA = defaultdict(dict)
SKIP = 2
# List of columns of interest
COLUMNS = ['test1Voltage', 'test1Current', 'test2Voltage', 'test2Current', 'currentstate',
           'BatteryHealth', 'Battylife(hr)', 'Battery test speed (mph)', 'BatteryLoading']


with open('testing1.log') as log:
    for _ in range(SKIP):
        next(log)
    for line in log:
        try:
            o = 1 if line[0] == '(' else 0
            if (lineno := int(line[o:].split()[0])) == 0 and len(DATA) != 0:
                break
            for c in COLUMNS:
                try:
                    i = line.index(c)
                    DATA[lineno][c] = line[i+len(c)+1:].split()[0]
                except ValueError:
                    pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Unable to process:-\n{line}...due to {e}', file=sys.stderr)

df = DataFrame.from_dict(DATA, orient='index')

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    test1Voltage test1Current test2Voltage test2Current   currentstate BatteryHealth Battylife(hr) BatteryLoading
0          13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
1          13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
2          13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
3          13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
4          13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
245        13.8V         2.1A        11.8V        12.1A  NORMAL_RUN(0)          100%         1hour            OFF
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Basically, the output should ignore the first two lines and start from 000, which your output above is correct. However, I got below error " ...due to not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) ". Do you have any idea? thank you again.

Comment: Yes - your data is not as you've described it. Try printing each line in the log file and you'll see what's wrong

Comment: I tested out the code and found that it only processes until index 255, once the log file contains more than 255, it will pop out the issue.

Comment: There is nothing in my code that can be affected by the value of the line number. Print the lines as you iterate over them. The last line printed before the exception arises is where your problem is. Add *print(line)* immediately before *try:*

Comment: you're right. I realized that inside each line, there might be some cases like:  Battery test speed  (mph)=15 ... BatteryLoading=OFF,  which means: there might be some spaces in the left side of the "=" , ( in this case, Battery  test  speed  (mph)=15, left side of the equal sign are all seprately by space)  which can cause the problem.

Comment: Without your actual data I can't help any further. It's up to you now

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I have provided and updated the data above.

Comment: one more thing is, it seems like your code skip a couple of pieces of info such as (  001 2019/02/14 00:00:20 [EVENT_NONE(0)] ) , is there any way to keep this info as well?  thank you

Comment: Of course it skips that. You said that the first whitespace delimited token in a line is a number. Therefore any line starting with a parenthesis must be invalid. You could add an explicit check for that condition but I can't help wondering what other garbage data you have